# Is it possible for a flask web app recieve data from client external USB device ex. RFID card reader?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, rfid, hid

I recently managed to [reverse engineer a POS RFID card reader attached to a touch screen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519273/getting-old-hid-rfid-reader-to-work-idealy-in-python-enviroment-by-reverse-engin)

Now I want to go deeper and use it in a Flask enviroment as a quick form of local user login authentication.
**But is it realy possible for a flask webb app to recieve data from such an external device on client side ?**
How could server get the data from a client browser that might not even know of the existence of such a device ?

The RFID reader does not simulate keyboard presses. I need to control it by HIDAPI package which writes and reads specific packet data.

Comment: If you can write and install an application on client side which can communicate with the device, this application can also communicate with a flask webapp (if there is a network connection, of course) by behaving basically like a web browser. Python's standard library provides functionality for this.

Comment: Maybe WebUSB or WebHID?